# QNetworkAccessManager and multiple simultaneous requests

Tags: multithreading, qnetworkaccessmanager

I need to connect to multiple sites (variable number of sites, may be over 100) and fetch some data in a loop for each site.

I create a thread and a QNAM for each site. (For each site QNAM must have different cookies).

All good for few sites, but when sites number is big I get

```
"Too many open pipes"
```

and crash.

Then I've tried using a single thread but is too slow because it won't fetch data from next site until current site reply is finished.

How can I make the application for maximum speed and without crashing?